# Handling Null types from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, null

I am using the `SqlDataReader` to get values from an SQL table and assign them to their respective variables. But in my table, `int` and `double` type columns have null values. So when I try to read a `null` `int` and assign it to an `int` variable, it crashes.

Here is how the values are being assigned to:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public int Map { get; set; }
public int TypeID { get; set; }
```

And this is where they are being read:

```
while (objSqlDataReader.Read())
{
    data= new data();
    emissiondata.ID = (int)objSqlDataReader["EFID"];
    emissiondata.Map = (int)objSqlDataReader["EFMappingID"];
    emissiondata.TypeID =(SqlInt32)objSqlDataReader["MobileTypeID"];
```

So if any of these is `null`, even when i'm debugging it, it crashes and doesn't continue.
How do I handle the `null` values in SQL and how do I assign empty values to my `int` if it is `null`?

Answer (score 3):

DBNull.Value works on DataTable rows, I'm not sure with SqlDataReader:

```
bool isNull = objSqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("EFID") == DBNull.Value;
```

If you use SqlDataReader's [GetSqlInt32,GetSqlDateTime, etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) for example, they are null-aware out-of-the-box.

Instead of unboxing:

```
emissiondata.ID = (int)objSqlDataReader["EFID"];
```

You do this instead:

```
SqlInt32 emissionId = objSqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(emissionIdOrdinal);
```

Then you can test for null directly:

```
if (emissionId.IsNull) ...
```

However, those methods need the column's ordinal to access value. You can setup those ordinals before your loop

```
int emissionIdOrdinal = rdr.GetOrdinal("EFID");
```

But if you really want C#'s null, you make a helper function for it instead:

```
public static int? ToNullable(this SqlInt32 value)
{
    return value.IsNull ? (int?) null : value.Value;
}
```

To access it with your nullable variable:

```
int? emissionId = objSqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(emissionIdOrdinal).ToNullable();
```

You can now test null directly:

```
if (emissionId == null)
```

An advice, try to change your class' properties to nullable types, precluding the need for you to use another variable:

```
public int? ID { get; set; }
public int? Map { get; set; }
public int? TypeID { get; set; }
```

Final code:

```
data= new data();
emissiondata.ID = objSqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(emissionIdOrdinal).ToNullable();
emissiondata.Map = objSqlDataReader.GetSqlInt32(emissionMapOrdinal).ToNullable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't test it now but you can try with `int?`, the nullable `int`. It's a shorthand for `Nullable<Int32>`. If `objSqlDataReader` can be cast to `int?`, change your fields to `int?` and add extra logic to property setter if you have to do something when value is null.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old, but if you are needing this answer after 2016-07-14:
When SQL Type is int, null
Use int? as the data type.

int? is a "nullable" int - so when SQL returns NULL for a column, the property value receives the value null.

Answer (score 1):

So, to find a possible answer I look at the documentation for the class you're talking about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx
There's a IsDBNull method. Not having C# around, this should work:

```
while (objSqlDataReader.Read())
{
   data= new data();
   if (!objSqlDataReader.IsDBNull(objSqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("EFID")))
   {
      emissiondata.ID = (int)objSqlDataReader["EFID"];
   } else {
      // Whatever you want to do when it is null
   }
   if (!objSqlDataReader.IsDBNull(objSqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("EFMappingID")))
   {
      emissiondata.Map = (int)objSqlDataReader["EFMappingID"];
   } else {
      // Whatever you want to do when it is null
   }
   if (!objSqlDataReader.IsDBNull(objSqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("MobileTypeID")))
   {
      emissiondata.TypeID = (int)objSqlDataReader["MobileTypeID"];
   } else {
      // Whatever you want to do when it is null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the query itself.  In Oracle, the function is `NVL()`.  Looks like you're using MS Sql Server, which uses:

```
ISNULL(YOUR_FIELD,0)
```

Usage and syntax for other RDBMS is here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: will this assign my variable as empty or as 0 ?

Comment: i was looking to keep it blank if it is null

Comment: @Tanny Fgh, I'm not sure what programming language you're using, but you typically can't cast a null to an `int` primitive.

Comment: @TannyFgh, if you need it to be blank, you need to be working with a string data type. It's simply not going to work the way you're casting a null to an `int`.  `int` is a number.  Always.

Comment: Well I tried ISNULL(YOUR_FIELD,0)
 in my query , it still doesnt assign 0 to the variable . It crashes

Comment: Well it says in the watch list :
  (int)objSqlDataReader["TypeID"] 'objSqlDataReader["MobileTypeID"]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' int